# excel copy paste to web page and flatten table

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, import-from-excel

Im looking for a way to flatten table while copying from Excel to web page. Biggest problem is that in my table I have multiple headers. I'm using this code for copy paste to transform my table as HTML table but I'm stuck on how to proceed.

Main idea is that I have lot of older information which need to be imported to database and for this still even copy paste version as the code below is workable for the moment if just get the data in right format. Also solution as in here: http://jsfiddle.net/duwood/sTX7y/ could be workable.

Current output:

```
<table>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>34B</td>
            <td>36B</td>
            <td>38B</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>50-506</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>BLANCO</td>
            <td>2475</td>
            <td>2835</td>
            <td>3190</td>
            <td>PCS</td>
            <td>$1.41</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>50-506</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>NEGRO</td>
            <td>1750</td>
            <td>2000</td>
            <td>2250</td>
            <td>PCS</td>
            <td>$1.41</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>34B</td>
            <td>36B</td>
            <td>38B</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>50-530</td>
            <td>yyy</td>
            <td>BLANCO</td>
            <td>195</td>
            <td>390</td>
            <td>515</td>
            <td>PCS</td>
            <td>$2.26</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>50-530</td>
            <td>yyy</td>
            <td>BEIGE</td>
            <td>95</td>
            <td>195</td>
            <td>260</td>
            <td>PCS</td>
            <td>$2.26</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Desired output:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>50-506</td><td>xxx</td><td>BLANCO</td><td>34B</td><td>2475</td><td>pcs</td><td>$1.41</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>50-506</td><td>xxx</td><td>BLANCO</td><td>36B</td><td>2475</td><td>pcs</td><td>$1.41</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>50-506</td><td>xxx</td><td>BLANCO</td><td>38B</td><td>2835</td><td>pcs</td><td>$1.41</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>etc</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Current code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('textarea[name=excel_data]').keyup(function() {
        var data = $(this).val();
        var rows = data.split("\n");
        var table = $('<table />');    
        for(var y in rows) {
            var cells = rows[y].split("\t");
            var row = $('<tr />');
            for(var x in cells) {
                row.append('<td>'+cells[x]+'</td>');
            }
            table.append(row);
        }
        $('#excel_table').html(table);
    });
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea name="excel_data" /></textarea>
        <div id="excel_table"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow! I'm not sure I understand your question. What is the input data? What is the desired output? The HTML table you posted? What does your current code produce? What do you mean by flattening the table?

Comment: Hello and thanks for fast reply. I made quick mock up in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sTX7y/315/ to clarify my input more clear. My input is the first table preferably just copy paste directly from Excel to text area etc on web form. Then this should be transformed to the below kind of table as you see on the fiddle example. My current code at the moment just transforms my copy paste input to HTML table as direct copy only.

Comment: So if I understand you right, you want to (1) produce all the `<td>` elements on the same row and (2) remove the rows with `34B, 36B, 38B`?  What about those rows is it that qualifies them as excluded? Is it that exact content? To remove them you need to put an `if` condition inside the `for(var y in rows)` loop, but to know what that condition should be you need to have an actual criteria to exclude those rows.

Comment: Do you want the data in the excel file to be inserted into a database?

Comment: yes this will be later for database entries. I played around quite a while and ended up generating following code: http://jsfiddle.net/sTX7y/318/. It might not be the most beautiful code but does more or less the function at the moment which I'm looking for.